# reducing simple special mod function to one line ( logically only , not tertiary operator)

Tags: python, algorithm, math, logic

I want a simple function that returns a mod of a number but in case of n%n I want value n instead of 0.

my function goes:

```
def special_mod(m,n):
    if  m%n != 0:
        return m%n
    else 
        return n
```

**What I really want is a single line logic that does not include conditions.**
*FYI : (m+1)%n , m%(n+1) will not work for all inputs( my inputs)*

Logically I want something like this

1. original mod  :   0 1 2 3 4 5     (for n =6) that i do not like
2. my special mod :  6 1 2 3 4 5     (for n =6) the cycle value goes to
   6 after 5  and 1 after 6

Can this be implemented without using condition like m!=n ?

Comment: Those two code blocks don't have the same logic, and the second one isn't valid Python.

Comment: Oh sorry i do not want it so did not tried using it . just edited (removed that section)

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you want this?  There are lots of different ways to write the branch, but without more specifics it's hard to know why you'd accept some and reject others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason: `(m-1)%n+1` wouldn't work, e.g.:

```
>>> n = 6
>>> [(m-1)%n+1 for m in range(12)]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

`m%n or n` or `(m-1)%n+1` will do the trick.

Comment: (m-1)%n+1 that is exactly what is was looking for thanks